# Is there a standard IPC technique similar to Named Pipes, without the requirement for a client to connect?

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I'm new to Named Pipes and it seems the basic normal operation is:

Server program:

1. Call CreateNamedPipe(..) to create an instance of a named pipe.
2. Call
   ConnectNamedPipe(..) to wait for the client program to connect.
3. Call
   WriteFile(..) to send data down the pipe.
4. Call CloseHandle(..) to
   disconnect and close the pipe instance.

Client program:

1. Call CreateFile(..) to connect to the pipe.
2. Call ReadFile(..) to get data from the pipe.
   Process or output the data.
3. Call CloseHandle(..) to disconnect from the pipe.

I would really like to be able to open a pipe and push data down it, without knowing/caring if there is a client. If there's no client, the data just gets discarded. Perhaps more a 'sink' than a pipe is a better way to describe this? The server doesn't handle connection attempts it just "throws the data" for anyone who happens to listen.

Is this possible using Named Pipes? If not, is this mechanism provided by some other technique on Windows (or available through STL)? My research so far implies a Named Pipe has a strict 1:1 relationship, 1 server and 1 client which suggests it can *almost* but not quite do what I want.

So far, using a file as a buffer is my only thought to totally decouple server and client but that is not a very good approach at all.

Comment: (If this idea has a proper name, please let me know so I can edit my question and look into it.)

Comment: you can create named section (file mapping in win32 terms) and write data to it. if somebody (client) want - it open section and read data

Comment: I'm not clear about the particular semantics. If the writer starts writing before a reader is created, can the reader catch up on missed data? It seems like you could use UDP sockets to localhost. They're connectionless. No client, no problem, but the price you pay is that you're serializing data even if nobody cares.

Comment: @MSalters Open to any ideas really. I wouldn't say catch-up is required but you'd want to avoid partial messages I guess. Although the client could be responsible for detecting start/end bytes if a `WriteLine` approach is not feasible. I hadn't realised UDP let you do 'fire and forget' in this way.

Comment: Well, UDP is packet-oriented, so as long as your messages are <64KB they'll fit and be delivered atomically. Locally, the only way to lose UDP would be an IP-stack buffer overflow, which is rather unlikely.

Comment: windows has [mailslots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/mailslots)

Comment: @ericpat well that's something I never heard of! 424 byte limit, how delightfully bizarre

Comment: @ericpat - in case mailslot - server can only read, and clients only write, but look like op want visa versa

Comment: @Mr.Boy From approaches listed in [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications), it seems **File Mapping** and **Windows Sockets** (UDP) might achieve your goal.

Comment: Seems a bit of a disparate mix if possibilities here. If anyone cares to summarise options in an answer that would be great - otherwise I may provide this myself as it actually seems quite a useful bit of information.